# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiogram'

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

I work in VS Code and I was asked to change the telegram bot script from python-telegram-bot library to aiogram. I've installed that via 'pip install aiogram' and still getting errors like ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiogram' and I don't know what to do.

```
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.types import ParseMode
from aiogram.utils import executor
import requests

TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN = 'XXXXXXXX'
COINGECKO_API_KEY = 'XXXXXXXX'

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token=TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

# Function to get token price from CoinGecko
def get_token_price(token_id):
    url = f'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids={token_id}&vs_currencies=usd'
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {COINGECKO_API_KEY}'}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    data = response.json()

    if 'error' in data:
        logging.error(f'Error from CoinGecko API: {data["error"]}')
        return None

    try:
        price = data[token_id]['usd']
        return price
    except KeyError:
        logging.error(f'KeyError: Could not find price for token with ID {token_id}')
        return None

# Command handlers
@dp.message_handler(commands=['btc'])
async def get_btc(message: types.Message):
    price = get_token_price('bitcoin')
    if price is not None:
        await message.reply(f'Ціна Bitcoin: {price} USD')
    else:
        await message.reply('Не вдалося отримати ціну для Bitcoin')

@dp.message_handler(commands=['eth'])
async def get_eth(message: types.Message):
    price = get_token_price('ethereum')
    if price is not None:
        await message.reply(f'Ціна Ethereum: {price} USD')
    else:
        await message.reply('Не вдалося отримати ціну для Ethereum')

@dp.message_handler(commands=['sfund'])
async def get_sfund(message: types.Message):
    price = get_token_price('seedify-fund')
    if price is not None:
        await message.reply(f'Ціна Seedify: {price} USD')
    else:
        await message.reply('Не вдалося отримати ціну для Seedify Fund')

@dp.message_handler(commands=['cgpt'])
async def get_cgpt(message: types.Message):
    price = get_token_price('chaingpt')
    if price is not None:
        await message.reply(f'Ціна ChainGPT: {price} USD')
    else:
        await message.reply('Не вдалося отримати ціну для ChainGPT')

@dp.message_handler(commands=['bnb'])
async def get_bnb(message: types.Message):
    price = get_token_price('binancecoin')
    if price is not None:
        await message.reply(f'Ціна BNB: {price} USD')
    else:
        await message.reply('Не вдалося отримати ціну для Binance Coin (BNB)')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from aiogram import executor
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Tried to create a new project (sometimes helps) and still same error

Comment: Use `python -m pip install aiogram`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use a virtual environment to avoid this issue. Virtual environments gives you the safety or installing and uninstalling easily and safe, plus, after being activated, they will solve your imports issues, due to their constancy.

To create:

```
python3 -m venv venv
```

- If you're using Windows, replace python3 with only **python**

To activate (Linux):

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

To activate (W10 - Powershell):

```
venv\Scripts\activate
```

With the venv activated, you just install what you need.

VS Code usually detects a virtual environment and it will ask you if you want to use it in your workspace :)

If you want to create a list of requirements, with they respective version, just use the following command and save everything in a requirements txt file.

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```